# javascript or jquery method of getting the source of an image if.. matching a certain pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, pattern-matching

I have a very old site with lots of files, for years it was put together and orgainized by year and in a particular fashion. Well I am upgrading the site. But in one section an "Articles" section I have close to 1,000 files, that I don't want to go through and manually edit one or two images per.

So I am hoping i can figure out a way to match the source tag where when the source is `../imgs/` I can find the actual file name being used and just change the source. My problem is finding the source attribute matching it to the dired and then getting the image name off the end of it. when the full path could be like

`../imgs/i2012/image-file.png`, `../imgs/i2011/image-file.png`, `../imgs/i2010/image-file.png`, `../imgs/i20xx/image-file.png` "image-file.png" just being an arbitrary example

Its hard to visualize a image tag, so I am adding one here for reference..

```
<img src="../imgs/i2012/example-image.png" alt="example-image" vspace="5" hspace="5" align="left" />
```

And to try and re-elaborate, not all images on the site stopped working, and all else, but the ones that have use an image source attribute similar to the above, but the `i20xx` and file name are different. So. I am trying to figure out how to take that image src tag. Find if it has `../imgs/` in it, and and if it does, I'd like to grab the "example-image.png" from it, so I can apply a new URL overall to the src attribute in the end using JS, which changing it isn't my problem, matching it so I can then get the file, and change the url appending that file to the url is my problem

Comment: Please show us your code, I don't really understand which problem you have with the `src` attribute.

Comment: This is not a task to be done in JS at the client. Instead, modify the markup files in your favourite editor. It will have powerful enough replacement tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the attribute starts with selector to match any images with a source starting with
`../imgs/`, and then iterate over those images, getting the filename into an array:

```
var images = [];

$('img[src^="../imgs/"]').each(function(i, el) {
    images.push( $(el).attr('src').split('/').pop() );
});
```

Comment: not sure how optimized that is.. but I like the idea.. I may have to run with that, its only a handful of images per file anyway. I just dont want to go through all those files..

Comment: If you intend to change the images "forever", I'd go with @Bergi, use a proper editor, and they have search and replace for multiple files, with regex and what not.

Comment: its not forever per say.. maybe with these files, but these particular ones are archive mostly so they aren't seen that often. Just all the images were moved to another server and are using a sub domain, and slightly different file structure, new articles are going in where thats controlled through server side methods where the source is generated from a single location pre render, just these files though barely seen need a solution for "right now" in time Ill get one of the interns to go through them all